# Ugly Armature Mesh Deformation in Edit Mode

Tags: mesh, armature, edit-mode

I've been trying to use shape keys to correct ugly armature deformation, but whenever I try to move a vertex in edit mode to where I want it to go it gives this super ugly curve thing.

[image]

[image]

Why are the edges curving like that?  It's supposed to be straight!  How to stop it from doing this?  It's very frustrating, what's the correct way to make it bend like an arm?

Comment: Is Preserve Volume checked under the mesh's Armature Modifier?

Comment: No, but checking it didn't help.  Not to worry though, I found the solution!  I'm going to put the answer to it now.  Thanks for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay!  I found the answer!

[image]

The problem was that I had a subdivision surface modifier on the mesh but I didn't apply it yet.  The armature was using the subdivision modifier to make it curve smoothly, but I was unable to edit those vertices that were making those weird curves because I didn't apply it to the mesh yet, all I was able to edit were the small amount of vertices that were there.  So I applied the modifier to my mesh and now it doesn't curve anymore because I have control of those vertices in edit mode.

[image]

Unfortunately I had some shape keys to the mesh already and I had to delete them in order to apply the modifier.  Oh well!

Comment: You would not have had to apply the subsurf modifier, if you had just moved it below the armature modifier.